# How do I get my Facebook app to show something on the top right corner?

Tags: facebook, notifications

Here is what the top right corner of my Facebook page looks like:

[image: Top right corner of Facebook home page]

What is the area under "Create Event" called? I see that some apps can put messages there like the one you see with "4 requests". How can I make my app put something there.

Also I see Birthday notifications there. When I click on the notification a box pops up where I can post to a friend's wall. Is it possible to make my app do that too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is where [application requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/requests/) shows. 
When an application/user sends you an application request, this is where Facebook put it

Please provide more info like the programming language you use and if this is your first application - that can help direct you in the right direction